# Changing tooltip colour/symbol in Salesforce chart using JS

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I am new to JS and need help in understanding it's scope in my use case.

The following function displays information on mouseover on the chart tool tip.

```
function renderTooltip(data, item) {
//this.setTitle(item.yField + ' : ' + item.value[1]);
var Data = item.value[1];
var TestData = item.storeItem;
this.update(''
        + '<table>'
        + '<tr><td><b>Name:</b>&nbsp;</td><td>' + TestData.get('Name') + '</td></tr>'
        + '<tr><td><b>Value:</b>&nbsp;</td><td>' + Data + '</td></tr>'

        );
var e = window.event;
var t = e.target || e.srcElement;
t.onclick=function(event){
window.location = "{!$Page.ABCDPage}?id="+TestData.get('Name')+'/'+Data ;
};
}
```

In addition to this , I want the tooltip symbol to change and the colour to be different , based on a ceratin value of a field in the record.

e.g if field 1== value 1 , symbol should be cross and colour blue , else box and colour green

Is that possible?

Comment: Assign different css class to your element based on value and write color and symbol rules in css

Comment: you mean inside javascript function?

Comment: Yes, inside `renderTooltip()` itself check for your value and assign css class to your tooltip element accordingly or if you are checking this value later then do at that time